# Setting table name for AppInsights REST API

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql

I'm trying to use the AppInsights REST API (api.applicationinsights.io). Let's imagine a query like this:

```
{
    "query": "customEvents | take 10; customEvents | take 10"
}
```

In the result output, I receive this:

```
{
    "tables": [
        {
            "name": "PrimaryResult",
            "columns": [...],
            "rows": [...]
        },
        {
            "name": "PrimaryResult",
            "columns": [...],
            "rows": [...]
        }
    ]
}
```

My question is: how can I set the "name" property to something telling? If nothing else, it's confusing to have them all be named `PrimaryResult`. Can I assume that the order of appearance is the same as in the query itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try using the [`as` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/asoperator).

for example:

```
customEvents | take 10 | as first_table;
customEvents | take 10 | as second_table;
```